# Detect resolution and framerate options for webcam devide with WPF Mediakit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-mediakit

I'm using WPF Mediakit's `VideoCaptureElement` to capture video from a webcam. I set the resolution with `DesiredPixelWidth` and `DesiredPixelHeight` properties. I would like to know how to detect the resolutions and frame rates with which the device can work. I don't know if it is posible with WPF Mediakit or another library. Do you know how to detect this capabilities?

Comment: I am not familiar with the MediaKit control but you can use emgu cv to display the stream/ file and get values Like FPS/Res/etc.

Comment: @DenisSchaf I used EmguCV before, and the problem that I see is that the OpenCV libraries are hundreds of megabytes of space and for a simple application it is too much.

Comment: i can agree with that.. i used it in the past and now wrote my own Libraries to get rid of it